# Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE

Tags: android, android-studio, jackson

Error:Execution failed for task ':openpayandroid:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
>       File1: /Users/ederpadilla/Downloads/driveappuble-drive-android-484430cd00e7/openpayandroid/libs/jackson-core-2.8.2.jar
>       File2: /Users/ederpadilla/Downloads/driveappuble-drive-android-484430cd00e7/openpayandroid/libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in your `app` gradle file

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}
```